# Passing asp.net databound object parameter to javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp Hyperlink inside a repeater. I want to call some javascript from the Nagivate Url and pass into the js function a property from the databound object.

```
<asp:Repeater id="repRecentDocuments" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:getRecentDoc('<%# ((RecentDocs)Container.DataItem).link %>')" Text='<%# ((RecentDocs)Container.DataItem).name %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button id="btnGetRecent" runat="server" style="display:none" OnClick="GetRecentDocument" />
```

But the property is not resolved and this is the value of the variable that is passed in.

```
<%# ((RecentDocs)Container.DataItem).link %>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using OnItemDataBound event on Repeater and use event handler as below

```
    <asp:Repeater id="repRecentDocuments" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepRecentDocumentsOnItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  />
</ItemTemplate>
```

```
protected void RepRecentDocumentsOnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e){
if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem) return;
var doc= (RecentDocs) e.Item.DataItem;
var hlink= (HyperLink ) item.FindControl("HyperLink1");    
hlink.NavigateUrl= string.Format("javascript:getRecentDoc('{0}')",doc.link);
}
```